# fuzzywuzzy with dictionary python

Tags: python, arrays, list, fuzzywuzzy

Below code works fine for array:

```
g = ['hello how are you', 'how are you guys','what is your name']
s = ['how','guys']
MIN_MATCH_SCORE = 38
guessed_word = [word for word in g if fuzz.token_set_ratio(s, word) 
                                               >=  MIN_MATCH_SCORE]
```

output:
'hello how are you'   'how are you guys'

how to achieve above with dictionary ?

```
p = [{1: 'hey guys'},
    {1: 'how are you all'},
    {1: 'hello guys, how are you doing'}]
```

expected output:

```
{1: 'hello how are you'}, {1: 'how are you guys'}
```

Hope i get some response.

Comment: This is a pretty basic traversal logic. Have you even tried this before asking out? All you need to traverse is element of the list p, which are dict, so get their values.

Comment: can you please tell with working example ?

Comment: please see my expected output.

Comment: There is an error in your list comprehension for `guess_word`.  If should be word not word[1] (i.e. word[1] is just a single letter).  With the current code guessed_word is [].

Comment: now it works please check, just removed[0] from word

Comment: Why does p have different string comments than g (e.g. 'hello how are you' in g vs. 'hey guys' in p)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list comprehension can be converted to the following to use dictionaries.

```
guessed_word = [d for d in p if fuzz.token_set_ratio(s, list(d.values())[0]) >= 
                                                       MIN_MATCH_SCORE]
```

Explanation:

```
 d iterates over the dictionaries
 list(d.values())[0] is the string portion of the dictionary i.e. 'hey guys', etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

p = [{1: 'hey guys'},
    {1: 'how are you all'},
    {1: 'what is your name'}]

s = ['how','guys']

MIN_MATCH_SCORE = 38
guessed_word= []

for i in p:
    for key,value in i.items():  #dict.items used to access the (key-value) pair of dictionary
        if(fuzz.token_set_ratio(s, value) >= MIN_MATCH_SCORE): #check the condition for each value , if it's satisfied create a dictionary & append it to result list
            dict={}
            dict[key]=value
            guessed_word.append(dict)

print(guessed_word)
```

The output will be :

> [{1: 'hey guys'}, {1: 'how are you all'}]

Answer (score 0):

#This one also works.
#g in p are in my usecase.

```
guessed_word= []
for p in g:
    for k,l in p.items():
        l = [l]
        #d = [fuzz.token_set_ratio(s,l) >= MIN_MATCH_SCORE]
        d= [word for word in l if fuzz.token_set_ratio(s, word) >= 
          MIN_MATCH_SCORE]
        guessed_word.append({k:d})
```